# spring integration dsl http outboundgateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl

We are trying to call a REST API using HTTP OutboundGateway using DSL. We are able to make the call using both GET and POST and getting the response as expected. However we couldnt figure a way to pass http headers while making this call using DSL. There are quite a lot of articles about XML approach but couldnt find out documentation with DSL

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("FileContentChannel")
                 .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://host:port/paymentinfo/")
                         .charset("UTF-8")
                         .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                         .headerMapper(headers)
                         .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                 .channel(MessageChannels.queue("APIResponseChannel"))
                 .get();
```

We tried with DefaultHttpHeaderMapper as well but it didnt work. Can you please guide us on this?

Thanks to Gary..it worked with this
**Update1**

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("FileContentChannel")
                     .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://host:port/paymentinfo/")
                             .charset("UTF-8")
                             .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                             .mappedRequestHeaders("pay*")
                             .headerMapper(headerMapper())
                             .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                  .channel(MessageChannels.queue("APIResponseChannel"))
                     .get();

@Bean
    HeaderMapper headerMapper() {
        DefaultHttpHeaderMapper headerMapper = new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
        String[] headerNames = {"payment-hdr1","payment-hdr2"};
        headerMapper.setOutboundHeaderNames(headerNames);

        headerMapper.setUserDefinedHeaderPrefix("");
        return headerMapper;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("FileContentChannel")
             .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("foo1", "bar")
                                  .header("foo2", "baz"))
             .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://host:port/paymentinfo/")
                     .charset("UTF-8")
                     .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                     .mappedRequestHeaders("foo*")
                     .expectedResponseType(String.class))
             .channel(MessageChannels.queue("APIResponseChannel"))
             .get();
```

Custom headers will (currently) get an `X-` prefix.

To avoid that use a customized `DefaultHeaderMapper` to map the required header patterns and use a `userDefinedHeaderPrefix` of `""`.