# How to create dynamically Spring Integration MessageChannels

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, message-channel

In the Spring integration the message channel can be configured like this:

```
    <int:channel id="get_send_channel" />

    <int:channel id="get_receive_channel">
       <int:queue capacity='10' />
    </int:channel>

    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="get.outbound.gateway"
       request-channel="get_send_channel" 
       url="http://localhost:8080/greeting"
       http-method="GET" reply-channel="get_receive_channel"
       expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

and used like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("http-outbound-gateway.xml")
public class HttpApplication {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("get_send_channel")
MessageChannel getSendChannel;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("get_receive_channel")
PollableChannel getReceiveChannel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HttpApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {
        Message<?> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("").build();
        getSendChannel.send(message);
        System.out.println(getReceiveChannel.receive().getPayload());
    };
}
```

How the MessageChannel can be created and registered dynamically?

Above code is from [this example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/integration/spring-integration-http-gateway-example/)

I have now tried this

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.rendezvous("getSend1"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/greeting").httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("getReceive1")).get();
```

with default poller, but there is the message:

```
preReceive on channel 'getSend1'
postReceive on channel 'getSend1', message is null
Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

So the configuration seems to be incorrect and the message is not fetch from the URL.

Comment: I used this example for another stackoverflow question regarding something else. I think it might be what you are looking for https://github.com/teplyuska/spring-integration-example

Comment: Yes, IntegrationFlows and Java DSL can be used, https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/java-dsl.html. Is it possible to read all the configurations (the URLs etc) from the database and configure the integration flows when the application starts?

Comment: I don't see why not. You could probably use the annotation @DependsOn for the class that configures your integration flows. Then you could depend on the repository where you want to read your configurations from.

Comment: Do you know how to get IntegrationFlows way (see up) working? It's quite near the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248152/spring-integration-dsl-http-outboundgateway but my implementation is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(this.integerMessageSource(), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(2000)))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("getReceive"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("postReceive"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8055/greeting-final").httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("postReceiveFinal"))
            .get();
}
```

This does get for the first URL, then posts the answer the second URL and then posts the answer to third URL and gets the final answer.